# How do i change chromiums name in the title bars and pages

Tags: settings, customization, chromium, titlebar

I'm building chromium from the source and I want to make it have my versions name instead of Chromium.

I've tried editing the branding in \src\chrome\app\theme\chromium but that didn't change much.

I expect it to change the words Chromium on every page like settings, new tab, in the hamburger menu etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to modify these files to change `Chrome` or `Chromium` references:

```
components/components_chromium_strings.grd

chrome/app/chromium_strings.grd

chrome/app/settings_strings.grdp
```

Just search for `Chromium` and `Chrome` in those files and replace them with your name. You will have to compile your Chromium again after making those changes.